# Adding an array to a for loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYIGs.png
Currently, DDi and DDj, if conditions are met will display message "Please select a device channel for Device1,2 or 3.", "Please select a different device channel for Device1, 2 or 3". I want it to say The actual names of the channels instead of Device1, Device2, etc. I don't know how to put in an array into my existing structure. I started below, but have a syntax error where the for begins.

```
If (HTSelection.DeviceDropDown1.List(0)) <> Empty Then
        
    Else
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 1"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 2"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 3"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 4"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 5"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 6"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 7"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device A: HT 8"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 1"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 2"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 3"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 4"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 5"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 6"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 7"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Device B: HT 8"
        DeviceDropDown1.AddItem "Channel_Not_Available"
    End If
    End Sub

Private Sub HTNextButton_Click()
    
    Dim DDi(1 To 3) As String
    DDi(1) = "Temperature"
    DDi(2) = "Adapter"
    DDi(3) = "USB"
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim DDj(1 To 3) As String
    DDj(1) = "Temperature"
    DDj(2) = "Adapter"
    DDj(3) = "USB"
    Dim ii As Integer

    'DDi = 1
    'DDj = 1
    Numberflag = 0
    DeviceFlagA = 0
    DeviceFlagB = 0
          'For DDi = 1 To 3
    For i = 1 To 3
        Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDi)
        If Device = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
        ElseIf Device = "Select Device" Then
            MsgBox "Please select a number channel for" & DDi, vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit For
        Else
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device A") Then
                DeviceFlagA = 1
            End If
            If InStr(1, Device, "Device B") Then
                DeviceFlagB = 1
            End If
               
              'For DDj = 1 To 3
            For ii = 1 To 3
            
                If DDi <> DDj Then
                    Device1 = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDj)
                    If Device1 = "Channel_Not_Available" Then
                    Else
                        If Device = Device1 Then
                            MsgBox "Please select different number channel for" & DDj, vbCritical, "Error"
                            Numberflag = Numberflag + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
    End If
            Next
            If Numberflag >= 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` too... it's hiding potential errors.

Comment: Remove ```on error resume next``` that is just complicating things, you have a whole bunch of issues here that are all being hidden by that line. ```DDi``` and ```DDj``` are string not integers, the ```for``` line needs to assign ```i``` a starting value. ```Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & DDi)``` is problematic aswell.

Comment: Will remove `On error Resume Next`. Starting value of `i should be `1. I am new to this, not sure how to integrate the array with my for. `Device = Me.Controls.Item` worked when I wasn't trying to use an array.

Comment: I assume ```Device = Me.Controls.Item``` should be 1, 2 or 3 so you would use ```i``` if you need the strings contained within the array you need to index the array with ```DDi(i)```

Comment: `Device` won't change in your loop because it references `DDi` so should probably reference `DDi(i)`.

Comment: The error is on the line after the For loop starts.  It is trying to append to a string by implicitly converting DDi  to a string: `” ... “ & DDI`.  This would work if DDi were an integer, but it isn’t, it’s an array.  So you’ll have to change that line to something like `... & DDi(i)`.

Comment: With `Device = Me.Controls.Item` is setting Device as string, because my dropdown list option is a string. I added picture and dropdown code for example. Okay, let me work on changes @SJR @RBarryYoung

Comment: @Lord45 , `DDi and DDj` declared as `Integer' why you set them as `String`

Comment: @everyone Please view my image. Original code would loop through and if "Temperature" was selected as Device A: Connector 1 and if "Adapter" was selected as Device A: Connector 1. I would receive a message that said, "Please select a different number channel for Device1. Now, instead of Device1, I want to reference the actual Device Name, "Temp, Adap, USB". I need help on structure. I see what you mean about making DDi & DDj an integer. I am learning as we go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ??

```
Private Sub HTNextButton_Click()
    Dim Device As String
    Dim DDi(1 To 3) As String
    DDi(1) = "Temperature"
    DDi(2) = "Adapter"
    DDi(3) = "USB"

    For i = 1 To 3
        Device = Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & i).Text
        If Device = "Channel_Not_Available" Or Device = "Select Device" Or Device = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please select a number channel for " & DDi(i), vbCritical, "Error"
            Me.Controls.Item("DeviceDropDown" & i).SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    '
    '
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: YES! Exactly, I copied that for DDj as well and implemented on my second part. Works perfectly.